# Writing time in a file in a for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

In windows 2008: I'm trying to zip and copy files to a backup server. I use command line/batch file, I log the result in a log file, I now want to log also the time for **each** file looped.

The backupZipCopy.bat batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo starting at %date% %time%>>c:\backup\resuZip.log
d:
cd \myDirectoryToBackup
FOR %%i IN (*.nsf)  DO (
echo %date% %time%>>c:\backup\resuZip.log 
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"  -bd u "\\backupServer\myBackup\%%~ni.zip" "%%~fi">>c:\backup\resuZip.log
)
```

**My problem:** The time is the **same** for all the batch duration (the time when batch **started** when I expected the real time in each loop). I already specify setlocal enabledelayedexpansion which doesn't help (so do I need this or not?).

NB timethis won't solve my problem since I need time in each loop.
NB2 I'm calling this batch from the window scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the line (the `( )` block is parsed as a single line), all `%foo%` variables are evaluated only once, before running the `for` loop.

The `enabledelayedexpansion` option *does* help. However, it doesn't change the parsing rules for the usual `%foo%` variable syntax. Instead, it introduces a new one – using `!` as delimiters.

```
for %%i in (*.nsf) do (
    echo !date! !time!>> C:\backup\resuZip.log
)
```

Be very careful with this, however, as the delayed expansion happens after `%foo%` variables have been expanded. Therefore it will result in unexpected output if a `%` variable has exclamation marks in it. The cmd.exe parsing rules are outright painful at times.

I strongly recommend you use a different language for your script. PowerShell would be a good choice, considering it's part of most recent Windows releases and it has tools for managing various Windows Server components.

Comment: yep, strongly encouraged: *something* other than cmd.exe ... the horror .. the horror.

Comment: I get your point @akira, but could you advice a better&simple way?

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: python, ruby, powershell? pick any .. not cmd.exe .. except when you have to for $reasons.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: PowerShell would be very useful to learn; it is part of Windows these days, and it also has cmdlets for managing _many_ Windows Server components. (I rarely deal with Windows myself, so I'd go with [Python](https://gist.github.com/grawity/9ce934629392914f79eb).)

Comment: Thanks a lot grawity ! You solve my problem. I note I should re write this! I guess l will re-write this in power shell... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/powershell-loop-through-files-in-directory is my starting point. One more time thanks!